# Issue with SerialPort in Node.js: "Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port"

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am facing an issue while using the SerialPort library in Node.js on Arch Linux. My goal is to open a serial port, perform an operation, and then close the port. However, when executing the following code, I encounter an error "Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port." Here is the implicated code:

```js
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')

async function sleep(delay) {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay))
}

async function open() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const p = new SerialPort({
      path: '/dev/ttyUSB1',
      baudRate: 9600
    }, err => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      console.log('opened')
      resolve(p)
    }
  )})
}

async function close(port) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    port.close(err => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      console.log('closed')
      resolve()
    })
  })
}

async function test() {
  let p = await open()
  p.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()))
  await sleep(5000)
  await close(p)
  p = null
  await sleep(5000)
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await test()
    await test()  
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message) 
  }
}

main()


// Output:
// opened
// closed
// Error Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port
```

on the second opening an error occurs, showing that the first connection, despite having been closed, still locks the port

If I remove `p.on('data' ... )` from the test, the error does not appear, which shows that it is entering 'flooding' mode that is messing things up.

did I miss something? Someone would have any idea ?

Environnement :

- Operating System: Arch Linux
- Node.js Version: 20.8
- SerialPort Library Version: 12